# How can I access children from bound innerHTML in Angular?

Tags: angular

The HTML is like this:

`<div [innerHtml]="someHtml"></div>`

While `someHtml` looks like this:

`public someHtml = '<code>test</code><code>another test</code>';`

I'm trying to get the code blocks using `ContentChildren`, but it is returning a length of 0.

```
@ContentChildren('code') public codeBlocks;

public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.codeBlocks); // returns length of 0
}
```

How can I get references to the code blocks that is being bound to the div via innerHtml? The HTML is actually pulled from a backend API, and my goal is to add a "copy" button to each block.

Comment: I was able to get references to the elements using `ViewChild` and then accessing `viewChild.nativeElement.children` - is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('codeWrap') public codeWrap: ElementRef;

  public someCode = '<code>hi</code><p>blah</p><code>test</code><p>blah</p><code>test</code>';

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const codeBlocks: HTMLCollection = this.codeWrap.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('code');

    Array.from(codeBlocks)
      .forEach((codeBlock): void => {
        const button = this.renderer.createElement('button');
        const text = this.renderer.createText('copy');
        const wrap = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        const parent = codeBlock.parentNode;

        // set wrap position to relative
        this.renderer.setStyle(wrap, 'position', 'relative');

        // set button styles
        this.renderer.appendChild(button, text);
        this.renderer.setStyle(button, 'position', 'absolute');
        this.renderer.setStyle(button, 'top', '0');
        this.renderer.setStyle(button, 'right', '0');

        // listen for button click event
        this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', (ev) => {
          const codeToCopy = codeBlock.innerHTML;

          console.log(codeToCopy);
        });

        // insert elements
        this.renderer.insertBefore(parent, wrap, codeBlock);
        this.renderer.appendChild(wrap, button);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have can have multiple `code` elements then you should use `@ViewChildren` and for single `code` element you can use `@ViewChild`.

Comment: `@ViewChildren('code') public codeBlocks: QueryList<any>;` returns a length of 0 elements, I believe it's because the HTML are actually bound to the `innerHtml` of the container, as the HTML is pulled from a backend API. The data from the API could contain multiple `<code>` elements.

Comment: Right, `innerHtml` are not the Angular compiled code so Angular will not be aware of it.

Comment: you can only use plain html in that exact situation

Answer (score 1):

`ngAfterContentInit` is applicable Content projection using `ng-content`/`ng-slot`. Use `ngAfterViewInit` should work. Also change your query to use `ViewChild` to query on rendered html.

```
@ViewChild('code') public codeBlocks;
```